# How does Prolog evaluate this clause?

Tags: prolog

This is how the clause looks like

```
splits(L, ([],L)).
splits([X|L],([X|S],E)):- splits(L, (S,E)).
```

**splits** should split the list L in two parts at every possible point and should return all the possibilities. 
A possible query is

**splits([1,2,3], Res)**.

The outcome is

```
Res = ([], [1,2,3]);
Res = ([1], [2,3]);
Res = ([1,2], [3]);
Res = ([1,2,3], []);
No
```

My Problem is, that I don't understand how splits work. I wrote it down for the above case, but still I don't know. I would appreciate if someone could explain me it.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @PaulButcher: What I don't understand is, how the it generally works. I wrote it down step by step, but I don't know how *Res* is produced.

Comment: @PaulButcher: For instances S and E are quite confusing.

Comment: Did you try doing a `trace` and step through the execution of a query?

Comment: What does your step-by-step writing down look like? How can that not give you the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a better understanding, first try using some more descriptive (or at least conventional) variable names:

```
splits(L, ([], L)).
splits([Head|Tail], ([Head|Tail2], Remainder)):- 
   splits(Tail, (Tail2, Remainder)).
```

So, your first version of `Res`, where it splits before the zeroth element, should be obvious:  It's an empty list and the whole list, and it matches the first clause.

For subsequent results, Prolog backtracks until it can find an alternative route that it hasn't taken before.  Given that `[1,2,3]` is a list with a head and a tail, it matches the `[Head|Tail]` in the other clause.  `Head` is `1`, and `Tail` is `[2,3]`.

So we now go round the sequence again, but this time, with `[2,3]` as the first argument.  In the first instance binding `(Tail2, Reminder)` to `([], [2,3])`, meaning that `([Head|Tail2], Remainder)` (i.e. `Res`, in your query), therefore, binds to `([1 | []],[2,3])`. `[1|[]]` is just `[1]`.  So there you get your second response.

Subsequent results are then derived in the same manner, choosing a different clause each time backtracking occurs.